# Error when connecting to postgresql on localhost with knex

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, localhost, knex.js

I am trying to connect to my local postgres db with knex but I keep getting this error.

```
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432 }

// Here is how everything is set up:
const connection = require('./db/knexfile.js').development;
const knex = require('knex')(connection);
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1', 'localhost', () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));

// Inside knexfile.js 
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      "user": "development",
      "password": "development",
      "database": "testdb",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 5432
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};
```

Additional information:
I am also running a React front end through webpack on localhost:3000 that sends http requests to 8080 through a proxy setting on the webpack server but this seems to be working.

I also have elasticsearch running on localhost:9200 and that seems to be wroking, too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had an incorrect version of postgres installed. I reinstalled postgres and no longer had the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Another, faster, approach is to connect to a local database is to use AF_UNIX sockets. You will have to give access rights to the Linux user that will host the application:

```
development:
  connection: {
    host: '/var/run/postgresql', // On Debian it is this one, check your distro
    database: 'database_name'
  },
```

This kind of access was measured to be 30% faster than going through AF_INET (TCP/IP) sockets.

Here an old article about that: [Performance of UNIX sockets vs TCP sockets](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-performance/2005-February/001143.html)